# How to speed up logstash pattern matching (grok)?

Tags: logstash

I have a log file with 200 MB. I feed the log file into logstash, and it is taking few hours to get the job done.

I am wondering if there's a way to speed things up? Perhaps running it in parallel mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at [here](http://logstash.net/docs/1.3.3/life-of-an-event) about how to speed up.

```
The default number of filter workers is 1, but you can increase this number with the '-w' flag on the agent.
```

For example, If your grok pattern is complex, you can use multiple filter worker(thread) to do the filter task and speed up logstash parsing the logs.

Answer (score 2):

Start with 10 workers like this:

```
`bin/logstash -f test.conf -w 10`
```

Will output

```
Settings: User set filter workers: 10, Default filter workers: 1
Logstash startup completed
```